# Is it possible to determine the yaw, pitch and roll of a face given the locations of the eyes and mouth? (picture included)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, math, opencv

[image]

Red dots = Left Eye Center (L), Right Eye Center (R), Mouth Center (M)

Purple Line = Line LR

Red Line = Horizontal line intersecting midpoint of L and R

Yellow Line = Vertical Line intersecting LR at M.x

Blue Line(s) = LM and RM

Green Line = Distance between X-Coordinates of L and R

Given this data, is it possible to determine the yaw, pitch and roll of a face?

All I have so far is the roll:

Roll = the angular difference between the left and right eye

Knowing that L, R and M all move relative to each other, it should be possible to calculate yaw and pitch in 2D space right?

My first thought was that yaw could be calculated as a ratio of the X coordinate of M relative to the distance of the x-coords of LR (The green line)

Any thoughts?

note: I'm using opencv

Comment: Mathematically speaking, I'm inclined to say no.  Three 2D points can't convey a 3D orientation.  I'm curious if anyone proves me wrong though.  :)

Comment: Nope.  Not enough info.

Comment: I'll observe that the horizontal and vertical lines can be derived from the three points and add no information.

Comment: If you knew the real-world distance between each of the three points *(as well as assuming that the face is not looking away from the camera, since then we couldn't see those features)* I believe you could narrow down to one of two orientations.  You might also need the distance of one of the points from the camera, I'm not sure.

Comment: Even if you have the metrics of the person, and know the distance to the camera (from some single reference point), it is impossible to tell "looking left" from "looking right", or to tell "looking up" from "looking down"

Comment: But is should be noted that your title says "eyes, *nose*, and mouth", while your description omits nose.  Since the nose projects in front of the face (though an unknown amount), the tip of the nose will change in relationship to the other points for looking left vs right or up vs down.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) which can compute translation and rotation of an object from cameras coordinates system. You need 3D model of the said object, which is 3D positions of points on the object, and find these points on the picture.

Comment: Do you think the the same idea could applied using the moments of the image? Perhaps waiting the moments based on where they lie on the face? i.e a moment located on the nose would be closer (relative to the viewer of the face) and one on the eye would be further, etc.

Comment: I highly doubt that. You need to use camera's intrinsics and precise locations of the object's points on image. Moments, AFAIK, have rather stable positions on an object, but they would still move due to perspective and occlusion. 
I suggest digging into some research papers about face pose estimations. Google scholar is a nice place to start. If You are a student or university worker, You should have no problems with access to most of the papers (at least from the university network).

Answer (score 2):

Without the outline of the face, and without knowing the size of the eyes or mouth, there are a multitude of orientations that are duplicates.  It seems like it should work, because our mind so easily uses those extra indicators to recognize and interpret facial movement and gestures.

If you are bored you can try it out!  Take a dry-erase marker with you into your bathroom.  Orient your face in some odd combination and mark your eye and mouth centers on the mirror.  Now move your face into other twists and turns that keep your eyes and mouth in the same position.

One quick one is to rotate your head 45 degrees to the left.  Mark your eyes/mouth positions, then rotate your head to where it is 45 degrees to the right, but move your whole head a half a head to the left.  You should be able to line the marks up there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Face++ API](http://www.faceplusplus.com/demo-detect/) returns roll, yaw, and pitch for each face in an image.

Also try a web search for "head pose estimation"